# Python. Как превратить string в переменную?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

```
movie = Movie()
print(dir(movie))
>>> ['actors', 'directors', 'id',  'country']

box_of_fields = dir(movie)

for item in box_of_fields:
    print(???)

# Мне нужно:
# 1 iter: print(movie.actors)
# 2 iter: print(movie.directors)
# 3 iter: print(movie.id)
# 4 iter: print(movie.country)
```

Каким образом можно реализовать такую штуку? Трюки с str и подобные в этом случае либо бессильны, либо я чего-то еще не знаю, чтобы из str сделать переменную

Comment: Лучше использовать `__dict__` в этом случае

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
for item in box_of_fields:
    print(getattr(movie, item))
```

или

```py
for item in box_of_fields:
    print(eval(f'movie.{item}'))
```

но первый вариант всяко лучше.